# KeyError: 'Records' while trying to process data from a kinesis InputStream in AWS lambda

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am trying to send data to a stream and then use kinesis firehouse to deliver the data to ElasticSearch, I am using python lambda function to convert the data to JSON before pushing, but the lambda is failing with below error.

```
  [ERROR] KeyError: 'Records'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 7, in lambda_handler
    for record in event["Records"]:
```

I am able to see the Records in the shard using sharditerator like below.

```
{
"Records": [
    {
        "SequenceNumber": "49599580114447666780699883212202628138922281244234350610",
        "ApproximateArrivalTimestamp": 1568741427.415,
        "Data": "MjAwNi8wMS8wMSAwMDowMDowMHwzMTA4IE9DQ0lERU5UQUwgRFJ8M3wzQyAgICAgICAgfDExMTV8MTA4NTEoQSlWQyBUQUtFIFZFSCBXL08gT1dORVJ8MjQwNHwzOC41NTA0MjA0N3wtMTIxLjM5MTQxNTh8MjAxOS8wOS8xNyAyMzowMDoyNA==",
        "PartitionKey": "1"
    },
```

I am using below lambda function to process the stream.

```
    import json
print("Loading the function")
success = 0
failure = 0
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    for record in event["Records"]:
        print(record)
        payload=base64.b64decode(record["Data"]).decode('utf-8')

        match = payload.split('|')

        result =  {}
        if match:
            # create a dict object of the row
            #build all fields from array
            result["crime_time"] = match[0]
            result["address"] = match[1]
            result['district'] = int(match[2])
            result['beat'] = match[3]
            result['grid'] =int(match[4])
            result['description'] = match[5]
            result['crime_id'] = int(match[6])
            result['latitude'] = float(match[7])
            result['longitude'] = float(match[8])
            result['load_time'] = match[9]
            result['location'] = {
                             'lat' : float(match[7]),
                             'lon' : float(match[8])
            }

            success+=1
            return {
                'statusCode': 200,
                'body': json.dumps(result)
                    }
```

But I am getting error in lambda function after sending data to the stream.

Answer (score 1):

What is the error and did you check cloudwatch logs to see what is happening? I feel as this will give you a good indicator of what is going on.

Comment: I have checked the cloudwatch error log and that says the same thing I mentioned,
```[ERROR] KeyError: 'Records'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 7, in lambda_handler
    for record in event["Records"]:```

Comment: Hey for troubleshooting, assign a variable the event["Record"] value and see what is even being passed to the event handler in the. After that, do a print(variable) and check the cloudwatch logs to see what is being sent to the lambda

Comment: Hi, if u see my post, I am able to print what is being passed to the event using CLI. But not able to iterate through the records using a lambda function.

Comment: It seems the key you are referencing can not be used with that. try assigning value = events["Records"] then try to get for records in value: